# Files stored in live distribution run from USB flash drive get deleted upon boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, live-usb

I have a live 32GB USB drive which boots Arch Linux. Whenever I try to save a file on the drive (using wget), it gets deleted/cleaned-up upon shutdown/booting.

For example, saving a file in `/root` using:

```
wget http://example.com/myfile.txt
```

And then using shutdown or reboot, the file will no longer be present on the drive.

How can this be prevented?

If I am not following one's standards on using a Linux distribution (in this case, Arch Linux), please notify me. I am still learning!

Output of `df /root`:

```
Filesystem                1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/arch_airootfs  33027952 852256  32159312   3% /
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
|-sda1        8:1    0   1.5G  0 part
|-sda2        8:2    0 296.6G  0 part

sdb           8:16   1  29.8G  0 disk
|-sdb1        8:17   1    31M  0 part

loop0         7:0    0 286.6M  1 loop /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs

loop1             7:1    0    32G  1 loop
|-arch_airootfs 254:0    0    32G  0 dm   /

loop2             7:2    0   256M  0 loop
|-arch_airootfs 254:0    0    32G  0 dm   /
```

Note that 298.1G is the size of the (Windows) Hard Disk and its partitions (sda, sda1, sda2) and sdb represents the actual USB drive.

Comment: Is this a live installation or a “normal” one? Did you shut dwown the system properly? What does `df /root` show?

Comment: @Gilles This is a live installation I believe (I used Win32DiskImager to write ArchISO). I use `shutdown` or `reboot` to shut down, and this outputs http://pastebin.com/z99ws4mq

Comment: Some live installations are designed to be non-persistent, so that you always reboot into a known state. I don't know if ArchISO is that way. I'm not sure how to tell. What's the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: `lsblk` outputs the following: http://pastebin.com/n67MADUB
Note that 298.1G is the size of the (Windows) Hard Disk and its partitions (sda, sda1, sda2) and sdb represents the actual USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

The root filesystem `/dev/mapper/arch_airootfs` is [mounted from a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) `/run/archiso/sfs/airootfs`. `/run` is an in-memory filesystem. What you have here is a live system that loads a system image into memory at boot time. You're saving the files into the in-memory copy, not onto the disk.

This type of setup is common in live systems, so that whatever you mess up on the live system, or whatever private data you manipulate, once you reboot, you get a clean system.

Some live systems support a persistent storage, either in a specific directory or through an overlay that allows storing modifications to the original image. But [Archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) doesn't appear to have that feature.

If you want to have persistent storage, you may be able to do that by creating a partition on the USB stick and mounting it. Be careful not to disrupt the live installation though. Since persistent storage isn't supported as a feature, it's probably not completely straightforward to add it.

The easiest way to get a system with persistent storage would be to make a “proper” installation of some Linux distribution onto the USB stick.